# postgres materialized view refresh performance

Tags: postgresql

There is a table t which is used in a mview mv, this is the only table in the mview definition.

```
create table t (c1 int, ..., c10 int);
-- there is a pk on say c1 column
create materialized view mv as select c1, c2...c10 from t;
---there is a unique index on say c5 and bunch of other indexes on the mview.
```

The reason there is a mview created instead of using table t, is that that the table gets truncated and reloaded every couple of hours and we dont want users to see an empty table at any point of time that's why mview is being used.

Using "refresh materialized view concurrently", this mview is being used by APIs and end users.

Couple of questions I have -

1. Whenever mview refresh with concurrently happens, does pg create another set of table and indexes and switch it with the orig? If no, then does it update the existing data?
2. If the usage of mview is pretty heavy does it impact the performance of the refresh process? Vice-versa, if the refresh is going on does the performance of mview by users take a hit?
3. The mview gets refreshed in couple of mins sometimes and sometimes it takes hours. When it runs for longer, there are no locks and no resource shortage, the number of recs in the base table is 6m (7.5gb) which is not huge so why does it take so long to refresh the mview?
4. Does mview needs vacuum/analyze/reindex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Question 1: `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY` updates the existing materialized view rather than building it from scratch. That's why it needs a unique index, so that rows can be identified.

Question 2: While the view can be used while it is refreshed, there might of course be a performance hit, since both operations use the same resources (CPU, I/O, memory).

Question 3: Impossible to answer without further information. Does the query behind the materialized view exhibit the same variation in execution time?

Question 4: `VACUUM` and `ANALYZE`, yes. `REINDEX` should not be necessary, unless you measure undue index bloat.

Comment: Thanks. Q1 - does it do upsert or truncate insert? any idea of how it applies changes? Is the mview update atomic or one can see few updated and few old records? Q3 - The query behind the mview is a simple select and it always consistently returns immediately. Could bloat to the mview could be causing the issue?

Comment: Read the comment to `refresh_by_match_merge` in [`src/backend/commands/matview.c`](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/backend/commands/matview.c;hb=HEAD). It all happens in a single transaction, so it is atomic.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz. Q3 reply - No, its a simple select from a single table. The base table gets truncated and reloaded with almost the same number of records. Mview is a simple select from this base table. 

The mview has around 10 indexes, 1 unique and 9 non-unique indexes. 

Population of the base tables takes about 2 mins, using "insert into select from table", but when the mview is created for the first time it takes 16 minutes. Even when I remove all but one unique index it takes about 7 minutes. Any clue as to why it is taking longer than the create of the base table (which is 2 mins).

Comment: The first select on a newly populated table will set the *hint bits*. That's one reason why it is a good idea to run `VACUUM` on a table after a bulk load.

Comment: Do the hint bits also get set after a table is truncated and populated with insert as select, or only after create table? In my case ran vacuum on the base table after truncate and insert, still the mview create takes 7 mins. Does hint bits get set for an mview as well? Also in pg_class I see toastrelid with some number, I assume it means there is a toast storage for the table. Could it be taking time as this table is going via toast for reads?

Comment: You'd have to capture a slow execution of the query with `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for an answer to that. If you vacuumed the table after inserting, hint bits can be ruled out as a cause. The next suspect is that the query is run before the statistics are updated. For that, run an explicit `ANALYZE` after the bulk load.